# Is there any way to call external Lookup REST service inside APIM policies?

Tags: azure-api-management

In my APIM policies, I need to do a lookup call to a separate REST Name-Value service and enrich the response.

Is there any way to call external Lookup REST service inside APIM policies?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Use send-request policy at any scope to make a callout. Later you can access result using policy expressions. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#SendRequest